# for each item in list, oracle pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a query:

```
select sq1.* from (
    select * from table1
    where type = '1'
    order by name
) sq1
where rownum <= 10;
```

but I have to run this list for types 2,3,a,b,c too. Is there a way to do something like this?

```
my @list = ('1', '2', '3', 'a', 'b', 'c');
for each my $item in @list {
    select sq1.* from (
        select * from table1
        where type = $item
        order by name
    ) sq1
    where rownum <= 10;
}
```

(Yeah, my code's in perl. It's all I know anymore.)

Comment: So you want the top 10 rows for each type?

Comment: exactly! I was going to try and figure out how to load the array list using a query. I can do all this in perl, but it would be much simpler to just have it in a query.

Comment: So do you want a single result set containing 60 items? (i.e. top 10 for type 1, top 10 for type 2, etc) Or do you need to return these as 10 individual sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sq1.* FROM (
    SELECT 
        tbl.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY name) AS rnk 
    FROM table1 tbl
    WHERE type IN ('1', '2', '3', 'a', 'b', 'c')

) sq1
WHERE rnk <= 10;
```